# Can I add a "Blank/ Not applicable" choice to a Wicket 1.5 CheckBoxMultipleChoice backed by an enum?

Tags: checkbox, wicket-1.5

In my application, every Foo has a Category.  Foo.Category is an internal enum in class Foo.  When creating a Foo on its given form page, the user selects a Category from a drop down typed to the enum.  However, this choice is optional.

Now, on another page, I want to be able to search Foo by name, and also by Category.  This search form has a `CheckBoxMultipleChoice<Foo.Category>` also typed to the same internal enum.  The checked values are sent to a DAO which queries my database with a "where category in" clause.

I want to add a "Blank/ None" choice to the check boxes, so that when sent to the DAO I can add a "or where category is null" to the query, if checked.  Since my check box is typed to the enum, is this even possible?

EDIT: Not sure if this will be important, but my enum has values designated by a SHORTNAME, but each has a String LongerAndMoreDescriptiveName, and the enum overrides `toString()` to return this value.  The SHORTNAME is what I store in the database, and used in the where clauses, but the Longer is what is shown on the UI.  I had briefly thought about changing to CheckBoxMultipleChoice and add the blank choice, but how would I then solve the discrepancy between values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible directly. There's no such thing as "No value" choice in CheckBoxMultipleChoice (like in DropDownChoice), because component's model is null when nothing is selected.

I think, you have two options:

1) Add constant Category.NONE to Foo.Category enum, and process it accordingly in the drop down choice where user selects category.

2) Create a wrapper class (something like Optional<Foo.Category>) for Foo.Category constants, and use it in the CheckBoxMultipleChoice instead of using Foo.Category constants directly. Instance of Optional<Foo.Category> will be able to have or not have corresponding Foo.Category constant so your processing of selection model should be appropriate.